# How to save serialized class to file and retrieve it again

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization

I use this code to record mouse and keyboard events and palyback it:

```
Namespace GlobalMacroRecorder
    <Serializable()>
    Public Enum MacroEventType
        MouseMove
        MouseDown
        MouseUp
        MouseWheel
        KeyDown
        KeyUp
    End Enum

    <Serializable()>
    Public Class MacroEvent
        Public MacroEventType As MacroEventType
        Public EventArgs As EventArgs
        Public TimeSinceLastEvent As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal macroEventType As MacroEventType, ByVal eventArgs As EventArgs, ByVal timeSinceLastEvent As Integer)
            MyBase.New
            Me.MacroEventType = macroEventType
            Me.EventArgs = eventArgs
            Me.TimeSinceLastEvent = timeSinceLastEvent
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I store events in events1:

```
Private events1 As List(Of MacroEvent) = New List(Of MacroEvent)
```

how to save events1 to a file and retrieve it again?

Comment: [**Serialization 101 - Part I: Binary Serialization - CodeProject**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254617/Serialization-Part-I-Binary-Serialization)